# Copy Entire Columns Based on Array and Paste it to a Sheet, in same Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy specific columns (in any order) where if the header matches the strings in an array those columns are copied to the target sheet EmptyCells.

Only the last column in the array is being copied regardless of the number of columns.

For Example:

1) HeaderName = Array("Business Impact", "Typology")
                - Only Typology Copied

2) HeaderName = Array("Business Impact", "Typology","ABCD")
                - Only ABCD Copied

I tried using variations of `Destination:=trg.Range(.......)`.

```
Sub Sup_DelCol()

    Dim i As Long, MaxColumns As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim HeaderName As Variant
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim trg As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    '##Source Worksheet
    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("general_report")

    '##Target Worksheet
    Set trg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    trg.Name = "EmptyCells"


    'Column Names
    HeaderName = Array("Business Impact", "Typology")

    'Copy the columns where the header matches the strings in the array
    MaxColumns = src.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For j = 0 To UBound(HeaderName, 1)
        For i = MaxColumns To 1 Step -1
            If src.Cells(1, i).Value = HeaderName(j) Then src.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=trg.Range(.....)
        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```

Expected Result (Based on Current Array):

Sheet EmptyCells (2 Columns) -
Business Impact (Column A) ; Typology (Column B)

Comment: The all important bit is possibly in the dots `Destination:=trg.Range(.....)`.

Comment: It is :) but instead of Destination:=trg.Range("A") for example , which is a Static value i need to add the Array (which can be N columns).

Comment: If you use `trg.cells(1,columns.count).end(xltoleft).offset(,1)` it will paste in the first empty column each time. If you want the column pasted in trg in the same column as it is in src just reference the column index. If you use `Match` you can do away with the `i` loop.

Comment: Thank You SJR, that did the trick :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand from your code, I think that what you meant to do was to cycle through your `.UsedRange.Cell`, instead of merely using `.Cell`.

Applying these corrections should do the trick. Change this code:

```
For j = 0 To UBound(HeaderName, 1)
     For i = MaxColumns To 1 Step -1
            If src.Cells(1, i).Value = HeaderName(j) Then src.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=trg.Range(.....)
    Next i
Next j
```

To this (I removed the inline `If` to improve readability):

```
For j = 0 To UBound(HeaderName, 1)
     For i = MaxColumns To 1 Step -1
            If src.UsedRange.Cells(1, i).Value = HeaderName(j) Then
               src.UsedRange.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy _ 
               Destination:=trg.cells(1,columns.count).end(xltoleft).offset(,1)
            End If
    Next i
Next j
```

> **Note**: I tested this code in my Excel and now it effectively cycles through all the headers.

#### Edit

- *Added @SJR code reguarding `rng` for completeness.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: Louis, tried your code but another issue which i have is how to use the array in the Destination:=trg.Range(.....) section. Since Array is Dynamic Range can be any size. If Array HeaderName has 4 Strings then Columns A,B,C,D are copied to Sheet EmptyCells. When i say 4 Strings it can be 5,6,7 etc..